# @BeforeAll not functioning as intended in JUnit5

Tags: android, kotlin, appium, junit5, ui-testing

I'm running UI testing on Android devices using Appium. We recently migrated to JUnit5 and I'm attempting to utilize the `@BeforeAll` class to make sure the app is in a good state before we continue to the next class.
Currently, the tooltip in Android studio is indicating that the function is never used. In the log I'm seeing a `junitException` saying that the method must be static. I haven't implemented `@TestInstance` yet, I'd like to be able to use `beforeAll` without it for now. I'm just confused why it isn't working since my `@beforeEach` and `@afterEach` are both working. The error and code are below.

```
org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: @BeforeAll method 'public final void com.bypass.automation.BaseTest.healthcheck()' must be static unless the test class is annotated with @TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS).
```

```
open class BaseTest {

    lateinit var driver: AndroidDriver<MobileElement>
    private val capabilities = DesiredCapabilities().apply {
        setCapability(APPIUM_VERSION, "1.19.1")
        setCapability(PLATFORM_NAME, "Android")
        setCapability(DEVICE_NAME, "Android")
        setCapability("appPackage", "com.ourpackage")
        setCapability("appActivity", "com.ourpackage.PassthroughHomeActivity")
        setCapability("automationName", "uiautomator2")
        setCapability("skipDeviceInitialization", true)
        setCapability("noReset", true)
        setCapability("full-reset", false)
        setCapability("enableMultiWindows", false)
        setCapability("unlockType", "pin")
        setCapability("unlockKey", "0000")
        setCapability("newCommandTimeout", "120")
    }


    @BeforeAll
    fun healthcheck() {
        val currentActivity = driver.currentActivity()
        println("Current activity is $currentActivity")
        if (currentActivity.contains("StationSecurePayActivity")) {
            println("Exiting Station Pay")
                CreditCardEntryView(driver).clickBackButton()
                }
        when {
            currentActivity.contains("kiosk") -> {
                Thread.sleep(2000)
                println("Exiting Kiosk")
                KioskView(driver).exitKiosk()
                println("Logging out")
                LogInProviderUtil(driver).logOut()
            }
            currentActivity != ".LoginActivity" -> {
                println("Logging out")
                LogInProviderUtil(driver).logOut()
            }
            currentActivity.contains(".LoginActivity") -> {
                println("Session was properly logged out. No action taken.")
            }
        }
    }

    @BeforeEach
    fun setup() {
        driver = AndroidDriver(URL("http://127.0.0.1:4750/wd/hub"), capabilities)
        driver.manage()?.timeouts()?.implicitlyWait(30, SECONDS)
        if (LogInProviderUtil(driver).isLoggedIn()){
            LogInProviderUtil(driver).logOut()
        }
    }

    @AfterEach
    fun teardown() {
        if (LogInProviderUtil(driver).isLoggedIn()){
            LogInProviderUtil(driver).logOut()
            driver.quit()
        }
    else {
            driver.quit()
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It will work.  I believe that any method annotated with `@BeforeAll` **must be static** (unless the "per-class" test instance lifecycle is used).   So it sounds to me like you should switch to that by adding this annotation to your test class:  `@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)`

Also, it is usual practice to make your setup and teardown methods public.   Also, I recommend use of Selenium-Jupiter framework (https://github.com/bonigarcia/selenium-jupiter/blob/master/README.md#appium) .   Good luck.

Comment: When I run my tests, I can see that tit's definitely not working. The beforeAll is causing an initialization error with the error message in the post. I'll try implementing @TestInstance

Comment: Static means in Kotlin that you have to move it into a companion object and annotate it with @JvmStatic.

Comment: Example of that here: https://dzone.com/articles/kotlin-and-junit-5-beforeall

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have an initialization block you may put it simply into
`init{}` method. And you don't have to annotate it.